# Derive the general solution of the ODE $x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=x^4$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

a) Obtain the general solution for $y=y(x)$ to $x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=0, x>0$

b) Derive the general solution of $x^3y'''-3x^2y''+6xy'-6y=x^4, x>0$

I can do part a) by looking for a solution in the form $y=x^r$ and differentiating, obtaining the general solution $y(x)=c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3$.

How would I proceed to answer part b)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will expect a particular solution of the form

$$ y_p=Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx +E$$

But you may leave out the $Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx$ because that will just leave $0$.

Substitute $ y_p=Ax^4+E$into the second equation and solve for $A$ and $E$.

The general solution will be

$$  y(x)=c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+Ax^4+E$$

Comment: Why is $Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx = c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3$?

Comment: Because $c_1,c_2$ and $c_3$ can take on *any* values. Any polynomial of that form will be annihilated by the DE.