# $x^3 y'''−3x^2 y''+6xy'−6y=x^4 \ln(x)$ (Euler)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential question;

I did Euler's rule with $x=e^t$ and found
$y = (At+B)e^{4t}$ then $t = \ln(x)$ therefore $y = (A\ln(x)+B)x^4$ but I can't find $A$ and $B$.

$$x^3 y'''−3x^2 y''+6xy'−6y=x^4 \ln(x)$$

$$y = C_1x+C_2x^2+C_3x^3+(A\ln(x)+B)x^4$$

How can I find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Plug in the particular solution $y_p=(A\ln(x)+B)x^4$ into the ODE and compare the coefficient of $x^4\ln(x)$ (which must be $1$ according to the RHS of the ODE), and the coefficients of $x^4$ (which must be $0$ according to the RHS of the ODE). You will get a pair of simultaneous equations which you can solve.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152251/derive-the-general-solution-of-the-ode-x3y-3x2y6xy-6y-x4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
x^3 y'''−3x^2 y''+6xy'−6y=x^4 \ln(x),
\\
\left(\frac{y''}{x^3}\right)'\cdot{x^{6}}+\left(\frac{y}{6x}\right)'\cdot{36x^{2}}=x^4 \ln(x),
\\
\left(\frac{y''}{x^3}\right)'\cdot{x^{4}}+\left(\frac{y}{6x}\right)'\cdot{36}=x^2 \ln(x).
$$